# Styling attributes nested inside id and class

Tags: css

[image]

What I want to do is remove the margin for the `p` nested inside the `id` then `class`.

Please note I cannot add a direct `id` or `class` for this `p` since this is a Wordpress site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this I believe is what you're looking for

```
.textwidget p
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

or if you specifically need that first paragraph tag

```
.textwidget p:first-child
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup that might work, but i do not want all p's inside this class to have no margin, i tried adding the #id .class p{ } but that did not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `#id`, `.class`, `p` and possibly `:first-child` selectors, like this:

```
#panel-w59fa3473baf71-0-1-0 .textwidget p:first-child {
   /* your styles */
}
```

Keep in mind that `id` might change since this is a Wordpress site. If that's the case you'll need to use one of the `class`es on that same element. Like:

```
.so-panel .textwidget p:first-child {
   /* your styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was my mistake, i have prefixed the p with a (.)

```
/*Style header whatsapp area*/
#panel-w59fa3473baf71-0-0-0 .textwidget p{
margin:0px;
}
#panel-w59fa3473baf71-0-1-0 .textwidget p{
margin:0px;
}
```